# How do I define a member function of a specialized template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class `ProcessPromise<T>` and its specialization `ProcessPromise<void>` that depends on `ProcessTask<T>`:

```
template<typename T>
struct ProcessTask;

template<typename T>
class ProcessPromise
{
public:
    ProcessTask<T> get_return_object();
};

template<>
class ProcessPromise<void>
{
public:
    ProcessTask<void> get_return_object();
};

template<typename T>
struct ProcessTask
{
};

template<typename T>
ProcessTask<T> ProcessPromise<T>::get_return_object()
{
    return { };
}
```

Can't figure out how do I define `ProcessPromise<void>::get_return_object()`?

Tried the code below:

```
template<>
ProcessTask<void> ProcessPromise<void>::get_return_object()
{
    return { };
}
```

but it does not compile, GCC error:

```
    prog.cc:30:23: error: template-id 'get_return_object<>' for 'ProcessTask<void> ProcessPromise<void>::get_return_object()' does not match any template declaration
30 |     ProcessTask<void> ProcessPromise<void>::get_return_object()
    |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:15:27: note: candidate is: 'ProcessTask<void> ProcessPromise<void>::get_return_object()'
15 |         ProcessTask<void> get_return_object();
    |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

MSVC error:

```
error C2910: 'awl::ProcessPromise<void>::get_return_object': cannot be explicitly specialized
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `template<>` prefix as shown below:

```
//no prefix template<> needed here
inline ProcessTask<void> ProcessPromise<void>::get_return_object()
{
    return { };
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jd3zerE5W)

Note that the `inline` keyword is added so that we don't get multiple definition error.

##### Explanation>

The reason we don't need the prefix `template<>` is that we're providing an ordinary **out-of-class definition** for the member function  of a full class template specialization. That is, we're not actually specializing the member function but instead providing an ordinary(non-template) out of class definition for that member function.